# [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; exception

Tags: ios

My application throw exception [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; in app delegate.

```
   //获取信息
   [PHTBannerManager getBannerdataWithSuccess:nil];
    //设置window
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.masterVC = [PHTMasterViewController new];
    self.window.rootViewController = _masterVC;

    //启动视频
    [self showMoviePlayer];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
#1  0x000000010560f170 in +[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:] ()
#2  0x0000000102122f2b in -[TLLaunchImage showLaunchStoryboard:maxTime:] ()
#3  0x0000000102122d96 in -[TLLaunchImage findLaunchImageMaxTime:] ()
#4  0x0000000102122acb in +[TLLaunchImage showLaunchImageInWindow:] ()
#5  0x0000000102197d66 in -[UIWindow(TLWindow) tlsw_becomeKeyWindow] ()
#6  0x00000001051114c7 in -[UIWindow _makeKeyWindowIgnoringOldKeyWindow:] ()
#7  0x0000000101eec006 in -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] at /Users/tong/Desktop/XB工作/iOS_duduDoctor/duduDoctor/AppDelegate.m:76
#8  0x0000000102183d30 in -[NSObject(TLDelegateSW) tlsw_application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] ()
#9  0x00000001050bb475 in -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] ()
#10 0x00000001050bbfbc in -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] ()
#11 0x00000001050bed2c in -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] ()
#12 0x00000001050bdbf2 in -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] ()
```

Comment: What is the actual exception?

Answer (score 0):

replace this line if you are using XIB

```
self.masterVC = [PHTMasterViewController new];
```

with

```
self.masterVC  =  [[PHTMasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PHTMasterViewController" bundle:nil];
```